# How to make if loop in grails?

Tags: grails, if-statement

I'm beginner in Grails, please help. I have this in my gsp

```
<div class="right66">                       
  <g:select class="time_pick" name="pick_day" placeholder="" from="${['Dani', 'Sati', 'Minute']}" valueMessagePrefix="book.category"/>
</div>
```

In translation: Dani = Days, Sati = Hours, Minute = Minutes. I need to save data in minutes but the user can choose if the input is in minutes, hours, or days. So I have to do if loop. I know how if loop works but I don't know how to write it in Grails. I was thinking something like this:

```
n=1
if(params.type=Dani){
    n= 3600
}else if(params.type=Sati) {
    n=60
}
def minute=params.minute*n
```

but how do I call that chosen input "Dani"? I can't write Params.type=Dani. Does if loop go in controller in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to convert your input to minutes, you should do that in your controller or a service. An `if` here is the same as in Java or Groovy. The inputs from your view will be in the `params` object in your controller with the same name as the input's id.

```
def minutes = params.input
if (params.pick_day in ['Sati', 'Dani']) {
    minutes *= 60
    if (params.pick_day == 'Dani') {
        minutes *= 24
    }
}
```

Comment: I have one more question: how define that g:select in my database- what data type I should use?

Comment: I'm not certain what you're asking, but if you want to store the value of the select, you probably want to use an Enum.

Answer (score 0):

groovy solutions in your controller

you can use below for looping ,but when do you end the loop either you have to decremented or increment the value of n to an end value like say 1.upto(n) means 1...100 ,but every time iu change its value and ur infinite some where...

```
List types = [] 
types = params?.type
```

def minute = 0;

```
1.upto(n) {
if(types[i]=='Dani'){
n=3600
}
else if(types[i]=='Sati') {
n=60
}
minute = params?.minute*n    
}
```